# How would I write this equation into Excel (-((N)/2)), -((N-1)/2)), - ((N-2)/2)),...,0,...,((N-2)/2), ((N-1)/2), ((N)/2))

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I need to input an equation into excel, I have set a cell to equal N and then I need another cell to hold the information (-((N)/2)), -((N-1)/2)), - ((N-2)/2)),...,0,...,((N-2)/2), ((N-1)/2), ((N)/2))

Comment: There are 2N+1 values there. Are you saying you want to put all of them in a single cell?

Comment: An array would be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array formula. Suppose,  your value `N` is in `C4` cell.

Select range in **one column** (for example `B1:B20`), then paste following formula:

```
=($C$4-(ROW(INDIRECT($C$4 & ":" & 3* $C$4))-$C$4))/2
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

---

If you'd like to store data in row, then select range in **one row**  (for example `B1:S1`), and paste following formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(($C$4-(ROW(INDIRECT($C$4 & ":" & 3* $C$4))-$C$4))/2)
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

Comment: That will give the same value in each cell though, whereas is b=1 and N= 4 the values should be -2, -1.5, -1, -0.5, 0, 0,5, 1, 1.5, 2

Comment: have you pressed __CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER__ to evaluate the formula or just __ENTER__?

Comment: CNTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Comment: For first formula you should select range in **one column** (for example `B1:B20`). For second formula you should select range in **one row** (for example `B1:S1`). Is it true for you? Formula works well for me

Comment: Yes that is what I have done, definitely gives the same answer throughout

Comment: Apologies, you have to select the range first. Never realised. Thank you for the help, is there any way you can do this without pre-defining the range?

Comment: unfortunatelly, with formulas not. But you can do it using VBA

Comment: It works for me (except you get numbers from high to low). You need to copy the formula into the range **before** pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER - I used this formula for the same thing, but it gives you low to high - =(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C4*2+1))-C4-1)/2

Comment: In the equation =($C$4-(ROW(INDIRECT($C$4 & ":" & 3* $C$4))-$C$4))/2 what is the purpose of the 3,

Comment: Difficult to explaing..so, the main purpose is to get something like this `Row("N:3*N")`. Where the number of rows will be exactly `3N-N+1 = 2N+1` (as dimmension of array)

Comment: If I wanted the results to be similar to those produced when using the FLOOR command within MATLAB, then how would I do it? i.e. to give N+1 results, therefore only giving integer values. So if N was 4 and b was 2 the results would be -1. -0.5, 0 , 0.5, 1

Comment: see my last comment to another your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093856/is-the-a-similar-command-within-excel-that-performs-the-same-as-the-floor-comm