# Is the a similar command within Excel that performs the same as the 'floor' command within MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab

The 'floor' command in MATLAB is defined as "Round towards minus infinity.
    floor(X) rounds the elements of X to the nearest integers
    towards minus infinity."

Is there a similar command within Excel, or does anyone know how to perform the same action within Excel?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use `=INT(A1)` formula. It rounds a number (from `A1` cell) down to the nearest integer. Here is [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/int-function-HP010062437.aspx).

Comment: If i wanted to do a similar task as x=(b/N)*(-floor(N/2):floor(N/2));  how could I do  that in excel?

Comment: what `-floor(N/2):floor(N/2)` do? it's the same as `-floor(N/2)/floor(N/2)`? It always returns -1?

Comment: No in matlab -floor(N/2):floor(N/2)  an array is created, how could i create such an array within excel

Comment: The result, `x`, will be an array. Select range in one column (for example `B1:B20`), then paste following formula: `=($A$1/$C$4)*INT(($C$4-(ROW(INDIRECT($C$4 & ":" & 3* $C$4))-$C$4))/2)` and press __CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER__ (see my asnwer on your first question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093364/how-would-i-write-this-equation-into-excel-n-2-n-1-2-n-2-2/21094380#21094380 for more details).

Comment: This gives me the same number throughout

Comment: See, please, my test workbook: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oui7gtjf4a2341n/Simoco_Test2.xlsx

Comment: Sounds silly, but when you press download where is it?

Comment: I think in _download folder_:)

Comment: Sorry but that isnt how I would expect the answer to be, via matlab the results would be -0.8000   -0.4000         0    0.4000    0.8000 for N = 5, b =2

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159057/excel-formula-to-do-the-same-as-x-b-n-floorn-2floorn-2-in-matlab/21159294#21159294

Comment: Since you've posted new question, I thing you can close this question