# Excel formula to do the same as x=(b/N)*(-floor(N/2):floor(N/2)) in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, excel, matlab

I'm converting my MATLAB code into an excel document but are having difficulty transferring the following formula across.

```
  x=(b/N)*(-floor(N/2):floor(N/2))
```

Which if for example b =2 and N = 5 
the results will be :

```
  x = -0.8000   -0.4000         0    0.4000    0.8000
```

and if b = 2 and N =6 the results will be:

```
 x = -1.0000   -0.6667   -0.3333         0    0.3333    0.6667    1.0000
```

Note: If N is odd there are N elements in x, if N is even there are N+1 elements in x.

Any ideas for how to write it within Excel?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is follows from comments to my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093856/is-the-a-similar-command-within-excel-that-performs-the-same-as-the-floor-comm/21093893?noredirect=1#comment31848753_21093893).

It's a really big array formula. Select `F3:F19` , enter formula in the formula bar and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.
(suppose your b in `A1` cell, your N in `C4` cell.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(($A$1/$C$4)*INT(($C$4-(ROW(INDIRECT($C$4 & ":" & 3* $C$4-1))-$C$4))/2),SMALL(IF(MATCH(($A$1/$C$4)*INT(($C$4-(ROW(INDIRECT($C$4 & ":" & 3* $C$4-1))-$C$4))/2),($A$1/$C$4)*INT(($C$4-(ROW(INDIRECT($C$4 & ":" & 3* $C$4-1))-$C$4))/2),0)=ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & ROWS(($A$1/$C$4)*INT(($C$4-(ROW(INDIRECT($C$4 & ":" & 3* $C$4-1))-$C$4))/2)))),MATCH(($A$1/$C$4)*INT(($C$4-(ROW(INDIRECT($C$4 & ":" & 3* $C$4-1))-$C$4))/2),($A$1/$C$4)*INT(($C$4-(ROW(INDIRECT($C$4 & ":" & 3* $C$4-1))-$C$4))/2),0),""),ROW(IDIRECT("1:" & ROWS(($A$1/$C$4)*INT(($C$4-(ROW(INDIRECT($C$4 & ":" & 3* $C$4-1))-$C$4))/2)))))),"")
```

here is my test [workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bd67xmvmeumxnl6/Simoco_Test3.xlsx)

Answer (score 0):

In Excel VBA:

```
Dim j As Integer = 0
Dim b As Double, N As Double, M As Double, k As Double
b = Cells(3, 3)
N = Cells(3, 4)
If Int(N/2) = N/2 Then
    M = N + 1
Else
    M = N
End If
For k = -(b/N)*(floor(N/2) To (b/N)*(floor(N/2) Step 2*(b/N)*(floor(N/2)/M
    j = j + 1
    x(j)=k
Next k
```